# spring boot batch to read all pdf filed from a folder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

spring-boot batch to read all pdf files from a folder.

I have a requirement to set up a spring batch process to read all files from a folder, and then send to other services.

No servicing is needed on the files, just read from folder & send it to SOAP service

I am new to Spring boot, please suggest how can this be achieved.

Comment: Hi @Shally Dhar, Apache Camel file component with Spring boot might be suitable for your usecase.